# I would like to count number of comments after 5 days ago

Tags: comments

this is my code, and the result shows always the total number of comments instead of number of comments after 12 february 2020.

I don't know why it does not working.

```
    #!/usr/bin/php

    <?php
    if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
        /** Set up WordPress environment */
        require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
    }

    $args1 = array(
            'status' => 'approve',
            'date_query' => array(
                array (
                   'after' => '2020-02-12 10:00:00',
                ),
             ),
          );

    $comments = new WP_Comment_Query( $args1 );

    $comms = get_comments( $comments );

    $nbr = count( $comms );


    echo "$nbr"
    ?>
```

thank you for your help

Comment: I think your issue is calling `get_comments()`. Once you've done your initial `WP_Comment_Query()` you should have just the comments you need, in an array. Try a `var_dump($comments)` to see. If you're then passing those comments into `get_comments()` it's likely `get_comments()` isn't recognizing them as an argument and so you get all comments instead.

Comment: Hi WebElain thank you very much for your help. You are right, the var_dump($comments) query shows the right result of comments starting at my query date. Now, my question is how can I do to count that number of comments result ?

Comment: Just use `count($comments)`

Comment: Thank you, yes I tried that but it return "1" while comments is not just one. :-(

Comment: Your var_dump should tell you what type of item it is (perhaps it's an object or a nested array) so you can get at the number of comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for WebElain to help me. This answer driving me to the right request.

Now it's ok. It is an object indead and I use something more simple with get_comments () query with parameter count enabled.

the final code is like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    /** Set up WordPress environment */
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ). '/wordpress/wp-load.php' );
}

$output = shell_exec('date --date="10 day ago" "+%Y-%m-%d %T"');

echo "$output";

// WP_Comment_Query arguments

$args1 = array(
        'status' => 'approve',
        'count' => true,
                'date_query' => array(
                    array (
                       'after' => $output,
                    ),
                 ),
              );

//$comms = var_dump( $comments );

$nbr = get_comments( $args1 );

echo "$nbr\n";

?>
```

Thank you.